# Android: Load database to memory vs queries over time

Tags: android, arrays, performance, sqlite

I'm working on a program that requires metadata information in order to populate some arrays. Let's say I have information like "Countries", "Districts" and a bunch of other metadata. That information is stored in a sqlite database. The program at some time need to load all the countries and iterate them in order to search for one. My question is: **What is the best way to proceed: Keep the metadata in an array after query them, or every time I need them I should query the database**?

Here's some more information so you can evaluate the performance:
Metadata tables (like countries): ~10
Estimated times I need to iterate the metadata: several (~100)
the arrays contains aprox. 5 fields (primitive types.)

Comment: What if **the data changes in between**? If you hold (a **very memory stressing** way) the data in memory, you always show the **old data**.

Comment: The data is metadata information. Which means it will be loaded from a webservice and it will never be changed, at least while the program is running

Comment: So, you are sure that noone changes the data on the server between your queries? Then you can keep the data in memory (or better copy them to a local db temporary table, so you can query them again and again)

Comment: Why should I copy them to a local db? The data is already stored on a sqlite database. It is populated the first time the user opens the app. Should I keep querying it every time I want to search for a country or should I save it into an array and iterate it. Is the query operation more stressful than an array iteration?

Comment: You said the data is fetched from a WebService. So not on a local db. Keeping the data in an array would be faster. But memory inefficient. You could get some OutOfMemory exceptions. And Android will erase the memory when the app is in background. So, you can't count on it.

Comment: Yes the data is fetched and then passed to a sqlite database. I'm not worried about the fastness of the operation. I'm more worried about the memory efficiency. From what you say it is better to query the database every time I need a country. Makes scence

Comment: If you are worried about memory efficiency then is bad idea to store the data in a _simple array_,  you can store it in a better data structure like `trie tree`. BTW, what decision did you take?

Comment: I decided to query them every time I needed. However a cache implementation should be good too

Answer (score 4):

1. If the amount of data is so large that if affects the amount of data available for your other data or for other app, you should keep it in the database and access it dynamically.
2. If the amount of data is rather small, and it's queried rather often, keeping it in memory is more efficient.
3. If the amount of data is rather small, and it's queried not very often, it will not make any noticeable difference what you do.

Your particular case is one of these three, but the only way to find out is to measure the performance yourself.

Comment: What do you define by "data that affects the amount of data available"?

Comment: I said "amount of data". You'd notice by your or some other app running out of memory and getting swapped out earlier.

Comment: I liked your answer. If the number of data is variable, do you think is good idea to measure the amount of data and then proceed?